# How can I backup windows on linux server?

Tags: linux, networking, backup, windows-backup

I have a linux server in my network and some windows servers and clients. I want to use the linux for backup windows servers and clients.

How can I do this and what is the best linux tool for this job.
I also need that tool has able to connect with ssh.
thanks.

Comment: (1.) Should the windows systems write to linux? or (2.) should the linux system read from each of the windows systems?  You asked for a "linux tool" which might imply (2.); however, you also specified "ssh" which might imply (1.).  Sniffleh provided a solution for (1.).  If you expect the linux system to use a tool to retrieve the backups (2.), then how are you planning on allowing the linux system to read the windows systems?  Are you planning on running sshd on each windows system?

Comment: The linux System Should read from each of the windows system. and I think of samba to read from windows system. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer should be rsync. I did this once, has a samba server on the linux one, mounted it as a network drive on windows (or was it the other way around?) and then ran some task to do the automated backup of w/e I wanted with rsync (for windows too) http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a good idea, but Windows 7 has an included tool to make periodically backups of the system. You can configure a Samba server then configure backups on Windows client on that Samba server.

Comment: It is possible, But I want a management point to backup and manage client's data.

Answer (score 0):

I would install duplicati on the windows, then backup to the server.